# Read Value from ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an array List as:

```
{IDS=[10, 12], SALARY=[10000, 20000]}
```

What I want is, I should be able to print like

```
IDS=10,12
SALARY=10000,20000
```

Code:

```
    ArrayList<HashMapImpl> ds = XmlUtils.getListFromXml("Abc", "XYZ", str);
    System.out.println("Array Content====>");
    Object[] elements = ds.toArray();
    for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        System.out.println(elements[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Is this an ArrayList with String elements?

Comment: Can you post the code? It's difficult to understand if it is an ArrayList of Strings or Objects as Hunter said.

Comment: @SaharHassan Post your code so we can see what you've tried already.

Comment: @Sahar: What's inside the hash maps?

Answer (score 0):

I just did the solution myself.

I added the following

Code:

```
        for(HashMapImpl map : ds){
           System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println("IDS: " + map.get("IDS"));
           System.out.println("SALARY: " + map.get("SALARY"));
        }
```